# asp.net core and System.Security.Cryptography.Native.Apple

Tags: macos, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I create new AspNetCore application on macOS and add EF Core package.
I try to save data into database using method SaveChanges() (DbContext class) and get next error:

> "System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL
>   'System.Security.Cryptography.Native.Apple': The specified module
>   could not be found."

I install openssl using following instructions:

1. brew update
2. brew install openssl
3. ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
4. ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/

OS : macOS(10.12.1)

project.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0-preview1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0-preview1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0-preview1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0-preview1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions": "1.1.0-preview1-final",
    "Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview3-final",
    "Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0-preview1-final"
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.0.0-preview3-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview3-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ],
      "buildOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true
      }
    }
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [
      "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%"
    ]
  },
  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "TTT"
  }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

UPDATE(add stack trace info)

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HL01MGG6QKIE": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'System.Security.Cryptography.Native.Apple': The specified module could not be found.
 (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at Interop.AppleCrypto.DigestCreate(PAL_HashAlgorithm algorithm, Int32& cbDigest)
   at Internal.Cryptography.HashProviderDispenser.AppleDigestProvider..ctor(PAL_HashAlgorithm algorithm)
   at Internal.Cryptography.HashProviderDispenser.CreateHashProvider(String hashAlgorithmId)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Implementation..ctor()
   at Npgsql.FrontendMessages.PasswordMessage.CreateMD5(String password, String username, Byte[] serverSalt)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ProcessAuthenticationMessage(String username, AuthenticationRequestMessage msg)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.HandleAuthentication(String username, NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.Allocate(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.OpenInternal()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(Tuple`2 parameters)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at TTT.Controllers.ValuesController.Get(Int32 id) in /Users/cmaker-note/Projects/AspNetCore/TTT/Controllers/ValuesController.cs:line 26
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionFilterAsync>d__28.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1.<RequestProcessingAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
```

Comment: I assume the .NET Core runtime is correctly installed?

Comment: Yea. I using this(https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos) instructions.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have missed one step.Here it is :

```
brew link --force openssl
```

All the steps :

```
brew update
brew install openssl
brew link --force openssl
```

**Reference :** [**dotnet restore (OSX)**](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/1161)

Comment: No, this is not help for me. After exec command("brew link --force openssl") I have message: "Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure...". I start looking for this message and found this issue https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3964#issuecomment-236493536. I think it is linked error.

Comment: did you see the reference link too on my post above ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem tonight when I updated this

```
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
```

to

```
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0-preview1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0-preview1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0-preview1-final",
```

When I reverted back to version 1.0.0 for all three it worked again.

The reason I upgraded was because I added a reference to this

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0-preview1-final"
```

and it wanted version 1.1.* for

```
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging"
```

Anyway, I downgraded

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0-preview1-final"
```

to

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.0.1"
```

And everything worked for me again. I expect this issue will go away when 1.1.* is ready for prime time.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```

actually point at valid files.
For me homebrew installed the openssl package but did not link it. 
Which I believe is what:

```
brew link --force openssl
```

does. But homebrew refuses to do this automatically due to security reasons. So if you simply want to try .NetCore you may just point at the actual install location. Which is:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2k
```

where it was for me.